# linq and string.compare/string.equals in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq

I have the below method and I want to try add in String.Compare

```
public List<Group> GetStudentCollectionByGroup(string anything)
{
    List<Group> groups = (from g in Groups
                          where 
                              (from t in g.Groupsz 
                              where t.StudentID == anything 
                                 || t.FirstName == anything 
                                 || t.LastName == anything select t).Count() > 0
                 select g).ToList();

        return groups;
    }
```

If I try `!=` rather than `==` on my client side whatever I type in the textbox I somehow get a return of the groups no matter what is typed. If I use `==` it will only return the group associated with what I type (belonging to that student ofcourse) so im hoping the String.Compare might help I just dont know how to construct the above code with it?

Comment: Might help what? What are you trying to accomplish? Currently, your method will return all groups where at least one `t` in the group has a StudentID, FirstName, or LastName matching the string passed the function.

Comment: `==` will be case sensitive, is that a problem? I usually use `String.Contains(anything)` is these situations as this does a case-insensitive partial search (at least when working with Linq to Sql - it translates to `LIKE %x%` I believe)

Comment: Yeah I would like it that some one can search a name lower or upper case however if I try != then it somehow returns the groups no matter what is typed. If I use case sensitive == then if I type anything other than the correct case sensitive name it wont return anything (obviously what I want) how can I return a name non-case sensitive but when I type something it doesnt recognise it wont show anything.

Comment: As atm if I only add one student with the Name bla and add that student to the group "mygroup" with the == I can return mygroup when I type bla in the textbox. (Which is fine) but.. if I use != if I type "whatever" into the textbox it will still return "mygroup"? Where as == doesnt.

Comment: I thought != would still only return that group belonging to student "bla" upper or lower case, it does! But it also returns groups when "anything" is typed into the textbox. So I thought String.Compare might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `==` with `!=` you are saying "return any `t` that has a student id other than `anything`, or a first name other than `anything`, or a last name other than `anything`" the only record that could fail that check would be `(anything, anything, anything)`.

What you want is a case insensitive comparison.

```
string.Equals(t.FirstName, anything, StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I agree with the answer, however, I would say that writing it as: `t.FirstName.Equals(anything, StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);` is more readable :).

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah Lucas is right I had trouble figuring out where it went when you first posted the answer but I got it in the end!

Comment: @Lucas: `NullReferenceException` if `FirstName` is nullable.

Comment: I suppose null values shouldn't appear in this particular case, but it's worth mentioning anyway. Thanks :).